# node.js What is wrong here.. trying to sort out welcome roles and welcome messages

Tags: node.js

I am not sure what is wrong with my code. I am trying to set up what is a welcome message as you can tell from below however, as you can see in the screenshot it doesn't do it right and I cant for the life of me understand why its not working. Help would be appreciated, thank you in advance. [Sceenshot of the outcome](https://prnt.sc/wq2k0v)

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember =>{
    let welcomeRole = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == 'member');

    guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole);
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('799707833586679828').send('Welcome <@${guildMember.user.id}> to our server!')
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're expecting; if you are trying to use string interpolation you need to use backticks. If you're trying to do something else you'll need to explain what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using quotes to send a string, maybe what you really want is [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember =>{
let welcomeRole = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == 'member');

guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole);
guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('799707833586679828').send(`Welcome <@${guildMember.user.id}> to our server!`)
});
```